# Unable to start Firebase Emulator Suite

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

This emulator suite was running perfectly yesterday. Now it won't start. I tried several methods but still not working:

1. Killing port on `8080`
2. Defining and running command in `package.json` to kill port `4400`, `4000`, `5001`, `5002`, `8080`, `9000`, `9090`, `9099`, `9199`
3. Running firebase command in an elevated terminal (command prompt)

The only thing I remember is yesterday, I straight up shut down my machine without closing opened programs and before it shut down completely, there was a Windows update, maybe that was the cause?

The command also generate a debug file, it look like this

`firebase-debug.log`

```sh
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.293Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.296Z] Command:       C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Rin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js emulators:start
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.296Z] CLI Version:   10.9.2
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.297Z] Platform:      win32
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.297Z] Node Version:  v16.14.2
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.299Z] Time:          Thu May 12 2022 18:21:28 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.300Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.306Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase-public.firebaseio.com/cli.json [none]
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.430Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.430Z] > authorizing via signed-in user (XXXXXXXXXX)
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.511Z] java version "1.8.0_331"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_331-b09
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.512Z] )
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.331-b09, mixed mode, sharing)

[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.518Z] Parsed Java major version: 1
[warn] !  emulators: Support for Java version <= 10 will be dropped soon in firebase-tools@11. Please upgrade to Java version 11 or above to continue using the emulators. 
[info] i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, firestore, storage {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hub"},"message":"Starting emulators: auth, firestore, storage"}}
[warn] !  emulators: It seems that you are running multiple instances of the emulator suite for project prismainventa. This may result in unexpected behavior. 
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.544Z] [hub] writing locator at C:\Users\Rin\AppData\Local\Temp\hub-prismainventa.json
[debug] [2022-05-12T11:21:28.553Z] Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:4400
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1313:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:1516:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:73:8)
[error] 
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Here is my config files

`firebase.json`

```json
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "stop": "npx kill-port 4400 4000 5001 5002 8080 9000 9090 9099 9199"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2"
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

The command I use is `firebase emulators:start`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out restarting my machine works, don't know why is this happen because when I tried to start it, my machine was on fresh boot condition (right after it turned on from a shut down state).

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you're connected to the internet.